# Need title of early sci-fi Mars movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need the name of an early sci-fi movie, 1950s or early 1960s. I'd call it a C-movie. It was a Mars landing, in a spaceship that looked basically like a coffee can. The seats in the ship were low-backed regular chairs. The elevator taking the crew to the surface was the slowest elevator ever seen. On the surface, they discovered a Mars monster which looked like a giant tin-foil ball spray-painted with lighting effects to make it spooky. I think there were only about 4 crew members. It was a wonderfully awful movie, lots of fun. I'd like to see it again and share it with friends.

Comment: I think it's Mission Mars! I remember some of it a little differently, and don't recall the groovy late 60's music at all! Thanks so much!!!

Comment: I was really surprised that the movie came out in 1968, because the ship, interior, alien and tin foil ball were so dumb. We were a year away from landing on the moon!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly better match, *[Mission Mars](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063311/)*, a 1968 film.

> Three American astronauts who land on Mars discover the body of a frozen Russian cosmonaut and a mysterious talking orb.

The "coffee can" ship is available around the two minute mark of the video above. Low-backed chair at 2:26. The tin-foil ball creature shows up around the 7 minute mark.

Comment: Fun fact: The gentleman getting his hair cut in this clip is Darren McGavin who played the dad in A Christmas Story.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the 1951 *[Flight to Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_to_Mars_(film))*. Looking at clips on the web, it's definitely low budget, and has the low-backed chairs. I haven't found a monster yet, but there are four crew members, wearing what look like garishly colored flightsuits.

[image: Movie poster 1] [image: Movie poster 2]

Comment: I don't think it's Flight to Mars, I don't remember any interactions with mars inhabitants. Maybe?

Comment: You've indicated that the other movie is the correct one, but I'll keep this answer in case someone's looking for a similar low-budget Mars movie.