# Movie about an alien probe that burns astronauts trapped on a planet

Tags: story-identification, movie, astronauts

I am looking for an old B-rated science fiction movie. All I remember are the astronauts are trapped on a planet, and there is a stationary alien probe that burns them every time they get near it. Does anyone know this film?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107510/need-title-of-early-sci-fi-mars-movie

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a long shot. But, the part about burning astronauts trapped on a planet sounds like Mission Mars starring Darren McGavin from 1968. It has an alien entity which burns the astronauts as they try to approach it.

The IMDB site is here:

http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0063311/

A YouTube clip can be found here. The part with the burning astronaut is at timestamp 7:30 - 8:00

And here's the alien:

[image]

Any of this look familiar?